Conservation Constraint Lemma Proof
im trying to understand the proof of a lemma
The lemma says:

A vector x with flows $x_{i,j}$ minimizing $\sum_{(i,j)eA} c_{i,j}x_{i,j} = z(0)$ also minimizes $\sum_{(i,j)eA} c_{i,j}^{π}x_{i,j}= \sum_{(i,j)eA}(c_{i,j}-π(i)+π(j))x_{i,j}= z(0)+\sum_{(i,j)eA}(π(i)+π(j))x_{i,j}$

The proof starts cosidering the potential of a node k from $0$ to π(k).
Then

$z(π)=z(0)+π(k)*\sum_{(i,k)eA}x_{i,k}-π(k)*\sum_{(k,j)eA}x_{k,j}=z(0)-π(k)b(k)
$

What I'm struggling to understand is what has been proven, and more importantly, where the term below originates from:

$π(k)*\sum_{(i,k)eA}x_{i,k}-π(k)*\sum_{(k,j)eA}x_{k,j}$

Seems like all arcs are ignored except those incident in k, but shouldnt we consider all the arcs?

You have omitted a minus sign:
\begin{align}
z(\pi) &= \sum_{(i,j)\in A} c_{i,j}^\pi x_{i,j} \\
&= \sum_{(i,j)\in A} (c_{i,j} - \pi(i) + \pi(j)) x_{i,j} \\
&= \sum_{(i,j)\in A} c_{i,j} x_{i,j} - \sum_{(i,j)\in A} \pi(i) x_{i,j} + \sum_{(i,j)\in A} \pi(j) x_{i,j} \\
&= z(0) - \sum_{(i,j)\in A} \pi(i) x_{i,j} + \sum_{(j,i)\in A} \pi(i) x_{j,i} \\
&= z(0) - \sum_{i\in N} \pi(i) \left(\sum_{j:(i,j)\in A} x_{i,j} - \sum_{j:(j,i)\in A} x_{j,i}\right) \\
&= z(0) - \sum_{i\in N} \pi(i) b(i)
\end{align}
Because the last sum is a constant, minimizing $z(\pi)$ is equivalent to minimizing $z(0)$.

Thank you, i was skeptical abount the fourth operation
